# Bootstrap 4 CSS - justify-content-center issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center each form. (sign in and signup ) inside their respective columns. It's OK for the first one, but not for the second one.

[image: screen capture]

Here is the css I am using. What could be wrong with it?

```
<section id="login">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col justify-content-center">
        <div class="w-75" style="background-color: grey;">
          <form>
            <h3>Sign In</h3>
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Sign In</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 justify-content-center" style="background-color: grey;">
        <h2>OR</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col justify-content-center">
        <div class="w-75" style="background-color: grey;">
          <form>
            <h3>Sign Up</h3>
              <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
              <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Sign Up</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want horizontal or vertical center. The ***simplest*** way to horizontal center is to use `mx-auto` (auto-margins) on the inner `w-75` divs...

https://www.codeply.com/go/orlziQBanZ

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="w-75 mx-auto" style="background-color: grey;">
                    <form>
                        <h3>Sign In</h3>
                        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Sign In</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 mx-auto">
                <h2 class="text-center">OR</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="w-75 mx-auto" style="background-color: grey;">
                    <form>
                        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
                        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The `align-items-center` on the `row` is for vertical centering.

Comment: thanks for feedback .. it runs well, however @webdevbooster answer seems to be more adapted to the flexbox usage ...

Comment: As a matter of fact ..; BOTH answers are right . :  d-flex in the div class=row AND  mx-auto in the inner div ...

Answer (score 1):

To enable flexbox for the columns (and thus make the `justify-content-center` class work) you need to add the `d-flex` class to each column as shown in the code snippet below.

And if you only want to center text within a column like the "OR" text, then you only need the `text-center` class for that column.

Note: That "OR" text will squeeze out of the column *when* the column gets too narrow for the content to fit. So, you should use responsive column classes there and use responsive column classes for the other columns as well. Because as the screen gets smaller, you'd probably want them to stack.

Here's the code snippet (without responsive column classes i.e. based on your code):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="login">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="w-75" style="background-color: grey;">
                    <form>
                        <h3>Sign In</h3>
                        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Sign In</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 text-center" style="background-color: grey;">
                <h2>OR</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="w-75" style="background-color: grey;">
                    <form>
                        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
                        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback ... as I am using flexbox, your answer seem to be more adapted to it...  @zimsystem is right too... mx-auto on the inner class  is fine...

Comment: As a matter of fact ..; BOTH answers are right . :  d-flex in the div class=row AND  mx-auto in the inner div ...